# Laravel eloquent conditional relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to set up a conditional relationship in eloquent model based on the value of table column, but it does not works.

This is the code that I am using:

```
 //RELATIONS
public function task_schedule()
{
    if ($this->task_schedule_id === 0) {
        return $this->belongsTo('TaskSchedule', 'hold_task_schedule_id', 'id');
    } else {
        return $this->belongsTo('TaskSchedule');
    }

}
```

Basically I want to use different column to get my child model defined in belongs to relationship.

scopeProfile($query) would not work for me because I dont want to retrieve the child in every single query and also **I am using Task->with('task_schedule')** in a lot parts of code.

Comment: You can't reference `$this` to get model's properties within the relationship methods as the model is not instantiated yet, it's still a query object when you call `->with(..)`. TLDR: you can't do that

Comment: Cool. Do you have any idea how I can do that in model class?

Comment: There's no real elegant way to do something like that. It's also usually an indicator of some bad design choices. Your best bet is to create different relationships and call them conditionally (using `->load(..)`) after you load the initial object.

Comment: I see! Thank you @devk!